# Extracting Data as columns for each month using only MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a database that looks something like this:

```
Year    Month        New Visitor?
2011    Jan            Yes
2011    Jan            No
2012    Feb            No
2012    Feb            No
2012    Feb            Maybe
```

I'd like Yes's and No's to be separate columns, per month so I can print it as a chart.I understand that to do this I'll need a result like this:

```
Year    Month         Yes       No     Maybe
2011    Jan            1         1       0
2012    Feb            0         2       1
```

How might I go about this using only MySQL?

Comment: What you want is called a 'PIVOT', which is not natively supported by MySQL.  You can do something similar by hand using @HopeIHelped's solution, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT `Year`, `Month`,
    COUNT(IF (`New Visitor?` = 'Yes', 1, NULL)) AS `Yes`,
    COUNT(IF (`New Visitor?` = 'No', 1, NULL)) AS `No`,
    COUNT(IF (`New Visitor?` = 'Maybe', 1, NULL)) AS `Maybe`
    FROM `table`
    GROUP BY `Year`, `Month`;
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! I needed an extra bracket in there though: `COUNT(IF ('New Visitor?' = 'Yes', 1, NULL)) AS Yes`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following (See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6971a/1)):

```
select year, month,
  sum(case when newVisitor = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end) yes,
  sum(case when newVisitor = 'No' then 1 else 0 end) no,
  sum(case when newVisitor = 'Maybe' then 1 else 0 end) maybe
from yourtable
group by year, month
```